# WooCommerce - Including product custom attributes in WordPress search query

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to improve my WordPress site search,
I want user's to be able to search by WooCommerce product attributes also.
I have created WooCommerce products and added all custom attributes(product attributes) through this code:

```
$attributes = array(
    '_image_number' => array(
        'name' => 'IMAGE ID',
        'value' =>0001,
        'is_visible' => '1',
        'is_variation' => '0',
        'is_taxonomy' => '0'
    ),

    '_year' => array(
        'name' => 'YEAR',
        'value' => 1988),
        'is_visible' => '1',
        'is_variation' => '0',
        'is_taxonomy' => '0'
    ),
);
update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_product_attributes', $attributes );
```

Alright, My Product is created and these attributes are stored in Postmeta as `meta_key=_product_attributes` and `meta_value=` serialized array of my attributes.
My Search form is:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" method="get" class="wp-search-form">

    <i class="oic-zoom"></i>

    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" placeholder="<?php echo get_search_query() == '' ? __('Type and hit Enter', 'vp_textdomain') : get_search_query() ?>" />

</form>
<br/>
```

In **`functions.php`** I have used pre_get_posts filter to modify query:

```
function ozy_custom_search( $query ) {

    if(!is_admin()) {

        if ( isset($query->is_search) && $query->is_search ) {

            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'product', 'post', 'page', 'ozy_portfolio' ) );
            $meta_query=array(
                'key'       => '_product_attributes',
                'value'     => $query->query['s'],
                'compare'   => 'EXISTS',    
            );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
            /*
            $meta_query=array(
                array(
                    'key'       => '_product_attributes',
                    'value'     => $query->query['s'],
                    'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
                ),
            );
            */
            // echo "<pre>";print_r($query);die;
        }
    }
    return $query;
};
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'ozy_custom_search' );
```

Result I am getting still is it searches into post title and post content, not getting searched in product attributes meta.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: Isn't the more accurated way but with your code you can change the compare parameter. Try "LIKE"